# Use of the word 'lawmaker' when referring to elected representatives

Tags: terminology, politics

Over the last few years I've noticed more news stories referring to elected representatives as 'lawmaker' rather than Senator, Congressman, Member of Parliament or whatever specific title they might enjoy.

I presume that it must be a matter for a local style guide that various organisations habitually use it; I first noticed it with Bloomberg ([e.g.](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-06-02/u-k-lawmakers-rebuke-cameron-in-favor-of-earlier-pollution-cuts.html)), but if you search any major news website, you will probably see examples.

In many situations the people being described are more than just lawmakers, they represent a constituency, sit of committees of oversight and similar roles that are at least as important as making laws. In the UK, they are members of Parliament, not just 'lawmakers'.

I have taken quite an irrational dislike to the word and I'm looking to make my opinion more rational. Why should 'lawmaker' be used, given that it seems to represent only a part of the responsibilities of the people generally described?

Comment: Noting you're from the UK, and your reference to MPs (*Members of Parliament* - not *Military Police*!), I assume you're asking specifically about US publications? If so, it might be worth mentioning that in the question - and tags.

Comment: See [syncedoche](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synecdoche?q=synecdoche) and [metonym](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metonym?q=metonym).

Comment: Perhaps someone knew the meaning of "legislature"...

Comment: Lawmaking is not only a significant part of what the Congress (the House of Representatives and the Senate) do, it is the only branch that makes laws under the Constitution. "No funds may be drawn from the Treasury except in consequence of appropriations made by law." The executive faithfully executes the laws. The judiciary adjudicates disputes and decides whether laws are Constitutional,   MCs also spend time helping constituents, overseeing Executive agencies, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself:  "[Lawmaking]seems to represent only a part of the responsibilities of the people generally described [as lawmakers]."

As Matt points out, "lawmaker" can be used synecdochically, since lawmaking is a "part" of the "whole" of what MCs (members of Congress) do.

I suggest lawmaking is a *significant* part of what MCs do, in part because of the far-reaching effects of the laws they pass; therefore, the synecdochal "lawmaker" is a legitimate substitute for a member of Congress.

Thank goodness for the various Acts of Congress over the years, such as the Clean Water Act or the Clean Air Act, which have safeguarded our air and water against large-scale polluters for decades.

Where does "lawmaking" rank in the top ten of MCs' work duties?  Ten percent?  Twenty-five percent?  Fifty percent?  I don't know, but such things could be determined.  I have a feeling, though, the amount of time spent devoted to this one area is not insignificant.

A cynic might suggest that MCs' number one job is getting re-elected!  Perhaps, therefore, we should call MCs "campaigners."

I have a feeling MCs would not be insulted one whit by the "lawmaker" appellation.  We have a saying in this country.  When faced with a seemingly intractable problem that demands a solution, sooner than later, we say, "There oughtta be a law!"

Lawmaking may not be a panacea for all that ails us as a country, but it's an integral part of good government nevertheless.

P.S.  As GEdgar points out, lawmakers are legislators.  Word Origin & History: 
legislature, 1670s, ult. from L. legis lator "a proposer of a law" (see legislator).  (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/legislature?s=t)